# jquery validation for asp.net web forms when javascript in browser is disable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I use Jquery validation in my project ( asp.net web forms)  but if user disable java script in browser , server side validation still work ? or i must use validation controls (asp.net) ?
how do i do for secure validation with Jquery when java script is disable in browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is written in JavaScript. So if JavaScript is disabled , Jquery validation or any other Jquery functionality won't work.

You can use [`<noscript>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML/Element/noscript) block to convey message to user to enbale Javascript in browser if it is disabled.
`<noscript>` block runs if Javascript is disabled.

```
<nocript>
  <h2>Please enable Javascript</h2>
</noscript>
```

Comment: so if java script was disable , how can i validate input user ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be a little confused about a couple of concepts here. As m hasan said, JQuery uses JavaScript (is written in if you prefer) which is a client scripting language, and as such, can be disabled on the client's machine (browser).

Server side validation works independently of the client, so the user disabling technology on their system should have no bearing on whether server side validation functions correctly or not.

If a user disables JavaScript in their browser, then you can't use JQuery. One option is to use the `<noscript>` blocks, as suggested by m hasan above (or below, depending on where this comment ends up).

From a security point of view, you should never rely solely on client side validation tools (such as JavaScript / JQuery). They should be seen more as aids to the user interface. All critical validation should always take place on the server.

Comment: thanks , you tell me : i use validation controls in asp.net web forms ? for example ( RequiredFieldValidate for not empty )?

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked on any .Net websites, but I believe that the ASP.Net validation tools use JavaScript for the client side validation, so these still may not work if the user disables JavaScript. Give them a try though and see what the result is